# Сортировка фото в MCImageManager (от TinyMCE)

Tags: сортировка, tinymce

Есть фото-менеджер **MCImageManager** совместно работающий с TinyMCE редактором.
Фотографии загружаются и отображаются в нем в каком-то случайном порядке.

Как управлять сортировкой в этом редакторе:

- по дате добавления
- по алфавиту А-Я
- по алфавиту Я-А

и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настоящее время способа управлять сортировкой нет. В TinyMCE пишут, что в будущем добавят, а сейчас надо лезть в исходники и вручную редактировать LocalFileImpl.php.

Comment: Натыкался на подобный коммент, правда не знал его срока давности, думал может чего изменилось.
Файл LocalFileImpl.php нашел, но проект у нас не на PHP, написан и работает на python, и пробовал его удалять, он никак не влияет на работу менеджера.
Есть еще предположения как его допилить можно?